# Can I reuse computed parameters of a base constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, parameters, constructor

Given the following classes (a toy example),

```
class A
{
    public string Description { get; }

    public A(string type, int age)
    {
        Description = $"Type: {type}, Age: {age}";
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public int Age { get; }

    public B(string type, DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime currentDate) : base(type, FindAgeParameter(dateOfBirth, currentDate))
    {
        Age = FindAgeParameter(dateOfBirth, currentDate);
    }

    static int FindAgeParameter(DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime currentDate)
    {
        return (currentDate.DayOfYear < dateOfBirth.DayOfYear) ? currentDate.Year - dateOfBirth.Year - 1 : currentDate.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
    }
}
```

is there a way to remember the value `age` that was passed to the base class, so that I don't have to calculate it again in the body of B's constructor? In a real situation, the parameter might also be a reference type where calling the same method again would not yield the same instance.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an approach with via introducing extra constructor (which I would argue is a bit cleaner option):

```cs
class B : A
{
    public int Age { get; }

    public B(string type, DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime currentDate) : this(
        type,
        dateOfBirth, 
        currentDate,
        FindAgeParameter(dateOfBirth, currentDate))
    {
    }

    private B(string type, DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime currentDate, int age) : base(type, age)
    {
        Age = age;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. A variable declared within the `base(...)` call will be available inside the constructor body! There are at least two ways to declare such a variable:

1. You can use an `out` parameter in the static function:

   ```
   class B : A
   {
       public int Age { get; }

       public B(string type, DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime currentDate) : base(type, FindAgeParameter(dateOfBirth, currentDate, out int age))
       {
           Age = age;
       }

       static int FindAgeParameter(DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime currentDate, out int age)
       {
           age = (currentDate.DayOfYear < dateOfBirth.DayOfYear) ? currentDate.Year - dateOfBirth.Year - 1 : currentDate.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
           return age;
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can use an `is` cast to define a variable:

   ```
   class B : A
   {
       public int Age { get; }

       public B(string type, DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime currentDate) : base(type, FindAgeParameter(dateOfBirth, currentDate) is int age ? age :  0)
       {
           Age = age;
       }

       static int FindAgeParameter(DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime currentDate)
       {
           return (currentDate.DayOfYear < dateOfBirth.DayOfYear) ? currentDate.Year - dateOfBirth.Year - 1 : currentDate.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
       }
   }
   ```

There is also another approach - you can store the value in a static variable of class B - but I consider that to be messy for multiple reasons.

Comment: _"There is also another approach - you can store the value in a static variable of class B - but I consider that to be messy for multiple reasons."_ - it is not messy it is plainly wrong as soon as there will be several threads which could create `B`'s.